# MooTools - find height of div id for certain a div class

Tags: class, html, mootools, offsetheight

I am trying to use offsetHeight to find the height of an element based on its class, so far I can find the height based on div id, but what if I have multiple classes assigned to the same id?

I adapted this jsfiddle to exemplify what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/VvrAs/80/

```
var idheight = $('textarea').offsetHeight;
    var classheight1 = $$('.field').offsetHeight;
    var classheight2 = $$('.field2').offsetHeight;
```

where field and field2 are div classes, and textarea is a div id

I want the undefined values to give the height of the div based on class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` selector behaves much like `querySelectorAll`, in that it will not return a *single* element, but a `NodeList` containing *multiple* elements, **even when only one element matches the query**.

NodeLists can be traversed like Arrays, so in your case:

```
var classheight1 == $$('.field')[0].offsetHeight;
var classheight2 == $$('.field2')[0].offsetHeight;
```

In essence, when you originally called `$$('.field')`, you asked MooTools to find all instances of elements containing the class `field`. It returned a NodeList of 1 item, but you'll still need to reference it via its array index.

Comment: Or simply get single elements via `document.getElement('.field').getSize()`